# Why are supertrait bounds other than the first not recognized on an associated type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, associated-types

This snippet is valid in Rust 1.26.1:

```
use std::ops::AddAssign;

trait Trait
where
    for<'a> Self: AddAssign<Self> + AddAssign<&'a Self> + Sized,
{
}

trait Trait2 {
    type Associated: Trait;

    fn method(u32) -> Self::Associated;
}

fn func<T2: Trait2>() {
    let mut t = T2::method(1);
    let t2 = T2::method(2);
    t += &t2;
}
```

Notice that `Trait` implements both `AddAssign<Self>` and `AddAssign<&'a Trait>` (in that order, which is important later). Therefore, in `func` we know that both `t += t2` and `t += &t2` should be valid. As seen [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4b2c1382c9eb887d74b89847bf111602&version=stable&mode=debug), `t += &t2` is valid, but [using `t += t2` isn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9b016bca1842519965e6d7df732772f6&version=stable&mode=debug):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:10
   |
19 |     t += t2;
   |          ^^
   |          |
   |          expected reference, found associated type
   |          help: consider borrowing here: `&t2`
   |
   = note: expected type `&<T2 as Trait2>::Associated`
              found type `<T2 as Trait2>::Associated`
```

I read this error as the compiler not recognizing that `AddAssign<Self>` is implemented for `T::Associated`, which is clearly wrong, as it implements `Trait`, which requires `AddAssign<Self>`.

If we change the order of the `AddAssign` bounds on `Trait` then the opposite holds: [`t += t2` is valid](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=38f43ce3e124b319f6ba6600d5c6ca68&version=stable&mode=debug) while [`t += &t2` isn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c6a71bc0cacb1ae4ed550a704225d651&version=stable&mode=debug).

A quick fix for the problem is to make `func` [generic over both traits](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1770e240ad20355eed43bfb68c4f24ff&version=stable&mode=debug):

```
fn func<T: Trait, T2: Trait2<Associated = T>>() {
    let mut t = T2::method(1);
    let t2 = T2::method(2);
    t += t2;
}
```

This shouldn't be necessary; the compiler can recognize one of the `AddAssign`s, why not the other? It seems the last bound is the one to be recognized.

My first suspicion was this this has something to do with dynamic dispatch.
I ruled it out since the order of the bounds shouldn't matter even in dynamic dispatch. I don't even think it uses it, since all types are known at compile-time using monomorphisation.

My current suspicion is a compiler bug where the typechecker doesn't account for generics on trait bounds when it is an associated type. It is easy to imagine such a specific case being overlooked.

What is going here?

Comment: I have never seen anything in the documentation to suggest that the order should ever be important, so this feels like a bug.

Comment: _"dynamic dispatch. I don't even think it uses it"_ — Correct. There is no dynamic dispatch here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug (or a combination of a few):

1. [Higher-ranked trait bounds on associated types are not elaborated (#50346)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50346).
2. [where clauses are only elaborated for supertraits, and not other things (#20671)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671)
3. [Constraints on associated types declared in subtraits do not propagate. (#32722)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32722)
4. [Unrecognized associated type bound on another associated type (#24159)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24159)

The workaround is to restate the bounds at every usage site:

```
fn func<T2>()
where
    T: Trait2,
    T::Associated: Trait,
{
    let mut t = T::method(1);
    let t2 = T::method(2);
    t += &t2;
    t += t2;
}
```

This should be addressed [when the type system moves](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48049) from its *ad hoc* implementation to [Chalk](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/chalk), a more principled solver for the types of problems a complicated type system creates.