# How to set trait bounds for the associated type of a trait bound of an associated type?

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I want to set trait bounds for the associated type of the trait bounds of an associated type:

```
trait UnsafeCast
where
    Self: Sized,
    <Self::Output as TryFrom<Self>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    type Output: TryFrom<Self>;
}
```

When I define this function, the compiler rejects it with errors:

```
fn run<T: UnsafeCast>(u: T) -> T::Output {
    T::Output::try_from(u).unwrap()
}
```

error is

```
error[E0277]: `<<T as UnsafeCast>::Output as std::convert::TryFrom<T>>::Error` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:9:11
   |
9  |   fn run<T: UnsafeCast>(u: T) -> <T as UnsafeCast>::Output {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^                                    - help: consider further restricting the associated type: `where <<T as UnsafeCast>::Output as std::convert::TryFrom<T>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug`
   |             |
   |             `<<T as UnsafeCast>::Output as std::convert::TryFrom<T>>::Error` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
...
13 | / trait UnsafeCast
14 | | where
15 | |     Self: Sized,
16 | | <Self::Output as TryFrom<Self>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug,
17 | | {
18 | |     type Output: TryFrom<Self>;
19 | | }
   | |_- required by `UnsafeCast`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `<<T as UnsafeCast>::Output as std::convert::TryFrom<T>>::Error`
```

The error says I have to set `std::fmt::Debug` bounds for `<T as UnsafeCast>::Output as std::convert::TryFrom<T>>::Error` even though I already set bounds in the first code.

The compiler also suggests adding trait bounds at the function definition, but I think it will be very repetitive when I define functions that use the type parameter with the `UnsafeCast` trait bound.

Is there an appropriate way to set bounds for trait associated type like above?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why are supertrait bounds other than the first not recognized on an associated type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50660911/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster So, the link you gave me means that I have to write trait bounds for each function definitions for now?

Comment: Yes. It's a bug.